# Polymer paper input error icons

Tags: polymer, icons, material-design, polymer-1.0

Polymer 0.x had a component paper-input-decorator, in which, if a paper-input had an error, an error message would show with an icon. Following is the code in paper-input-decorator.

```
<div class="footer" layout horizontal end-justified>
      <div class="error" flex layout horizontal center hidden?="{{!isInvalid}}">
        <div class="error-text" flex auto role="alert" aria-hidden="{{!isInvalid}}">{{error}}</div>
        <core-icon id="errorIcon" class="error-icon" icon="warning"></core-icon>
      </div>
      <div aria-hidden="true">
        <content select=".counter"></content>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Polymer 1.x has an element  paper-input-error that can be used to show error messages. But is there a way to add an icon to this if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`<paper-input-container>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container) to recreate a `<paper-input>` with an icon inside its `<paper-input-error>`. The following Polymer element template shows an error icon inside `<paper-input-error>` when the input is non-numeric:

```html
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }

    /* In 1.x, the <input> is distributed to paper-input-container, which styles it.
    In 2.x the <iron-input> is distributed to paper-input-container, which styles
    it, but in order for this to work correctly, we need to reset some
    of the native input's properties to inherit (from the iron-input) */
    iron-input > input {
      @apply --paper-input-container-shared-input-style;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      font-size: inherit;
      letter-spacing: inherit;
      word-spacing: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
      text-shadow: inherit;
      color: inherit;
      cursor: inherit;
    }
  </style>

  <paper-input-container>
    <iron-input slot="input" auto-validate>
      <input is="iron-input" pattern="\d+">
    </iron-input>
    <paper-input-error slot="add-on">
      <iron-icon icon="icons:error"></iron-icon>
      <span>Only numbers are allowed!</span>
    </paper-input-error>
  </paper-input-container>
<template>
```

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for this! I get an error Cannot resolve '--paper-input-container-shared-input-style' custom property set.

Comment: @user2689782 No problem :) That CSS custom property is [defined in `paper-input-container.html`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/08d7513/paper-input-container.html#L122).

Comment: I don't see it in my version of paper-input-container. This is version 1.x

Comment: This is from `paper-input` version 2.2.3, which works with Polymer 1.x. (Note `paper-input-container` is included in the `paper-input` package.)